# Filtering by multiple values and Summing Up object in a List in Java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `List<MyObject>` and this list contains thousands of objects. I want to filter this list by `recordNo` and `year`. If there is any object, which has same `recordNo` and `year` values, I want to sum up their `amount` and `sum`.

After filtering the list and summing up the values I want to create a new `List<MyObject>` and this list is not going to contain any duplicate objects(by `recordNo` and `year`)

MyObject structure:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyObject{

    private Long recordNo;
    private Integer year;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private BigDecimal sum;
}
```

Current example list Output:

```
[
    {
     "recordNo": 10,
     "year": 2021,
     "amount": 10,
     "sum": 100,
    },
    {
     "recordNo": 10,
     "year": 2021,
     "amount": 20,
     "sum": 200,
    },
    {
     "recordNo": 10,
     "year": 2020,
     "amount": 20,
     "sum": 100,
    },
    {
     "recordNo": 10,
     "year": 2020,
     "amount": 5,
     "sum": 20,
    },
    {
     "recordNo": 11,
     "year": 2021,
     "amount": 10,
     "sum": 200,
    }
]
```

Desired List Output:

```
[
    {
     "recordNo": 10,
     "year": 2021,
     "amount": 30,
     "sum": 300,
    },
    {
     "recordNo": 10,
     "year": 2020,
     "amount": 25,
     "sum": 120,
    },
    {
     "recordNo": 11,
     "year": 2021,
     "amount": 10,
     "sum": 200,
    }
]
```

What is the best way to create desired list output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using streams:

- to read about [groupingBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector) collector
- to read about [reduce](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) method

```java
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create some test data
        List<MyObject> objects  =  new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            obj.setSum(BigDecimal.TEN);
            obj.setAmount(new BigDecimal(i));
            obj.setYear(2020);
            obj.setRecordNo(1L);
            objects.add(obj);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            obj.setSum(BigDecimal.TEN);
            obj.setAmount(new BigDecimal(i));
            obj.setYear(2021);
            obj.setRecordNo(2L);
            objects.add(obj);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();
            obj.setSum(BigDecimal.TEN);
            obj.setAmount(new BigDecimal(i));
            obj.setYear(2021);
            obj.setRecordNo(3L);
            objects.add(obj);
        }


        // groupingBy collector produces a key for object grouping
        // we group by 'recordNo' and 'year' fields
        Map<String, List<MyObject>> grouped = objects.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> obj.getRecordNo() + " " + obj.getYear()));


        // groupingBy colletor returned a map, but we need only
        // its values
        List<MyObject> groupedAndSummedUp = grouped.values()
                .stream()
                .map(group -> {
                    return group.stream()
                            .reduce((obj1, obj2) -> {
                                // actual 'merging' of objects is happening here
                                BigDecimal newAmount = obj1.getAmount().add(obj2.getAmount());
                                BigDecimal newSum = obj1.getSum().add(obj2.getSum());
                                obj1.setAmount(newAmount);
                                obj1.setSum(newSum);
                                return obj1;
                            })
                            .get();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution based on Stream API [`Collectors::toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) with merge function and `Supplier<Map>` to maintain order of the elements from the initial stream is as follows -- the values of the computed map is wrapped into new `ArrayList`:

```java
List<MyObject> totals = new ArrayList<>(
    data               // initial List<MyObject> read from JSON
    .stream()          // Stream<MyObject>
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        obj -> Arrays.asList(obj.getRecordNo(), obj.getYear()), // group by recordNo and year
        obj -> obj,    // a copy may be created if needed
        (o1, o2) -> {  // merge function
            o1.setAmount(o1.getAmount().add(o2.getAmount())); // total amount
            o1.setSum(o1.getSum().add(o2.getSum()));          // total sum

            return o1;
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new // maintain order of initial data
    ))
    .values() // get Collection<MyObject> with totals grouped by key
);
```

For `data` created like this to match input JSON:

```java
List<MyObject> data = Arrays.asList(
    new MyObject(10L, 2021, new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(100)),
    new MyObject(10L, 2021, new BigDecimal(20), new BigDecimal(200)),
    new MyObject(10L, 2020, new BigDecimal(20), new BigDecimal(100)),
    new MyObject(10L, 2020, new BigDecimal(5), new BigDecimal(20)),
    new MyObject(11L, 2021, new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(200)) 
);
```

The result is as follows (using custom `toString` in `MyObject` class):

```
{recordNo: 10, year: 2021, amount:30, sum:300}
{recordNo: 10, year: 2020, amount:25, sum:120}
{recordNo: 11, year: 2021, amount:10, sum:200}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list by using `Comparator`. Create a class(`MyComparator`) implementing comparator, add logic for sorting according to your condition, like first based on `recordNo` and then on `year` (You can decide for ascending or descending order).

You can then call `Collections.sort(<yourList>, new MyComparator());` It will sort the current list.

Now as required you can create a new List, and keep on checking if previous object's values are required to be sum up with the current object or not. If its true you can create a new object with the summed up values and put it in the new list.

P.S. Since you have not provided any working logic, not providing the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you want to do at the end but you can check out Java8 streams this will filter out objects you dont want and leave you only wanted items

```
Stream.of(list or array).filter(obj->condition);
```

[ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an iterative (non-stream) approach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<MyObject> objects = List.of(
            new MyObject(10L, 2021, new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(100)),
            new MyObject(10L, 2021, new BigDecimal(20), new BigDecimal(200)),
            new MyObject(10L, 2020, new BigDecimal(20), new BigDecimal(100)),
            new MyObject(10L, 2020, new BigDecimal(5), new BigDecimal(20)),
            new MyObject(11L, 2021, new BigDecimal(10), new BigDecimal(200))
    );

    Map<Long, Map<Integer, MyObject>> mapped = new HashMap<>();

    for (MyObject object : objects) {
        var recordNo = object.getRecordNo();

        if (mapped.containsKey(recordNo)) {
            var objectMap = mapped.get(recordNo);
            var year = object.getYear();
            if (objectMap.containsKey(year)) {
                var objectFromMap = objectMap.get(year);
                var myObject = new MyObject(recordNo, year, object.getAmount().add(objectFromMap.getAmount()), object.getSum().add(objectFromMap.getSum()));
                objectMap.put(year, myObject);
            } else {
                objectMap.put(year, object);
            }
            mapped.put(recordNo, objectMap);
        } else {
            Map<Integer, MyObject> value = new HashMap<>();
            value.put(object.getYear(), object);
            mapped.put(recordNo, value);
        }
    }

    // convert map to lists
    var newList = mapped.values()
            .stream()
            .map(a -> new ArrayList<>(a.values()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(newList);
}
```

And an approach with streams

```
var collect = objects.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                MyObject::getRecordNo,
                Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getYear)))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(a -> a.values()
                .stream()
                .map(values -> values.stream()
                        .reduce((myObject1, myObject2) -> {
                            Long recordNo = myObject1.getRecordNo();
                            Integer year = myObject1.getYear();

                            var newAmount = myObject1.getAmount().add(myObject2.getAmount());
                            var newSum = myObject1.getSum().add(myObject2.getSum());

                            return new MyObject(recordNo, year, newAmount, newSum);
                        })
                        .get())
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(collect);
```